# Headless duck not quacking on MacOS

Tags: libreoffice

I'm trying to convert an ODT file to a PDF file with the following command:

```
/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice.bin \
    --headless --convert-to pdf file.odt
```

LibreOffice comes up momentarily and... that's it.  `file.odt` exists and is readable.  The current directory is writable.  I was expecting `file.pdf` to be created but nope, nothing.

Any hints on how I might debug it?

Comment: hm not sure why the downvotes.. are the arguments being passed correctly?

Comment: Maybe because the title is absurd and the question is off topic? [FAQ: What can I ask here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)?

Comment: @JamesA --  Maybe "my duck won't quack" isn't a common expression where you live.  It means something won't do the only thing you expect it would always do. And off-topic?  The question isn't open-ended, vague, or a matter of opinion.  What's your complaint?

Comment: @Malvolio: Perhaps because questions here are supposed to be related to programming, and this isn't? I don't see "LibreOffice command-line conversions" as a programming question at all, and it certainly doesn't seem to match any of the bullet topics in the [faq].

Comment: @KenWhite -- I guess so, but I notice that the "Related" column shows five very similar questions (two that might actually contain the answer!)

Comment: @Malvolio: That doesn't matter. A lot of the questions were prior to the existence of other StackExchange sites like [su]. Also, the context of the question matters; yours has no programming content (or context), but is a simple command-line use question. Again, the [faq] is pretty specific about the types of questions that are on topic *now*. (And if two might contain the answer, then this is most likely a duplicate.) :-)

Comment: @KenWhite -- so it's your belief that what's actually *in* StackOverflow is no indication of what *should* be in StackOverflow, but instead I should consult a list of Frequently Asked Questions, which is authoritative?  If you think there's some other forum that would be better suited, I think that would be a much more convincing position.

Comment: @Malvolio: At one time, questions were considered on topic here that were about operating system use. That's what led to the creation of [su] in the first place - the need to separate programming and non-programming questions. The [faq] has the use guidelines for this site, which is authoritative. If you object to the guidelines, you can post to [meta] and request that they be changed (or suggestions about where your question would be more suited).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, you cannot run LibreOffice headless if you are already running it... uh, "headful".  Or you can, but it doesn't do anything.

Or as some might say, the duck won't quack.